# Is $f$ differentiable and continuous at$ (0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

We have $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ definied by:

$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
x^2,  & \text{for $y \gt0$} \\
0, & \text{for $y =0$} \\
-x^2, & \text{for $y \lt0$} 
\end{cases}$

Is $f$  continuous and differentiable at $(0,0)$ ?

How do I do that with this function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the nature of the graph suggest anything to you about whether it is differentiable? Are you saying "It's obvious from the graph that it's differentiable but how can we prove it rigorously?" or are you saying you have no guesses as to whether it is or is not differentiable?

Comment: I have no guesses as to whether it is or is not differentiable. ^^

Comment: In that case you may be failing to understand what differentiable means and maybe that's what you need to ask about. Do you know what the graph looks like? Do you know how to instantly recognize non-differentiability by looking at a graph?

Comment: Note that if $Df(0,0)$ exists, $f$ is automatically continuous at $(0,0).$

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clear that $f$ is continuous at $0$.
Now let's try and tackle differentiability.

Each half-plane $H_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\, y>0\}$ and $H_2=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,|\, y<0\}$ is an open set on which $f$ is clearly differentiable, with $\nabla f(x,y)=2x$ on $H_1$ and $\nabla f(x,y) = -2x$ on $H_2$.
Now, as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, $\nabla f \to 0$ on both $H_1$ and $H_2$.
This hints us that $\nabla f=0$ at $(0,0)$.

Let's recall the definition.
A function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be *differentiable at $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$* if there is some linear map $D_x:\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$\lim_{h\to0}\,\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-D_x(h)\rVert}{\lVert h \rVert}=0.$$

In our case we have $x=0$.
Let's try it with $D_x$ being the zero map $($following our suspicion from the calculations of $\nabla f)$.
We then need to check if

$$\lim_{(a,b)\to 0}\frac{|f(a,b)|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=0.$$

To that end, observe that

$$0\leq \frac{|f(a,b)|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} = \frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\leq \frac{a^2}{|a|}=|a|,$$

so that by the squeeze theorem as $(a,b)\to 0$ so too does $|f(a,b)|/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.
It follows from the definition that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and its gradient at $x=0$ is $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Any function $g(x,y)$ that satisfies $|g(x,y)|\le x^2 + y^2$ everywhere is differentiable at $(0,0),$ with $Dg(0,0)$ equal to the zero linear transformation. The proof is straightforward: Just check that

$$g(x,y)= g(0,0) + 0 + o((x^2+y^2)^{1/2}).$$

In our problem, we have $|f(x,y)|\le x^2 \le x^2+y^2,$ so by the above $Df(0,0)$ is the zero linear transformation.